# openpyxl xlsx file cell value = none

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsx, openpyxl

I want to read an xlsx file using openpyxl.
Here is the typical code i use:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("example.xlsx")
sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name="Sheet3") or wb.get_sheet_by_name(name="Section3")
for rownum in range(1, sh.get_highest_row()):
    print str(sh.cell(row=rownum, column=1).value)
```

In this example i'm able to find values from the 1st column.
The problem is i have data in the second column and others column but in output i got None....

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: I have never worked with python but then if you want data from other columns, shouldn't you be incrementing the value of `column` in the loop using a variable like you are doing for the row?

Comment: I know, it's just for testing, column=1 works and when i test with column=2 not, neither column=3 or 4 ... Only "some" column returns something. no clue why cause there is data in every col.

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value of `sh.get_highest_row()`

Comment: I have the correct number of rows. if i print rownum it goes until the last one, in the excel i have 11500 rows and the output stop at this number.

Comment: In VBA a range would be like `Range("A1:A" & lastrow)`. In python does `range(1, sh.get_highest_row())` depict something like that?

Comment: Usage: cell(coodinate=’A15’) or cell(row=15, column=1)
So using range it will give a variable whitch is incremented, here rownum until the end.

Comment: Anyway if i make print sh.cell(row=155, column=2).value
I get None, instead i should have something

Comment: Till the time someone from python comes to the rescue.. lemme try a shot at this :) What does `range(1, sh.get_highest_row())` evaluate to?

Comment: Yes it returns the maximum row index containing data
Thank you anyway

Comment: Qucik question.. unlike vba-excel, does the first column start with `0` in python? If yes then are you referring to the right column?

Comment: Yes it start also to 0. I have the same problem if i use eg: 
print sh.cell(coordinate='i20').value

Answer (score 1):

It works with the library xlrd. 
The excel file is generated with a java library.IT look's problematic with this way of creation. Open it with excell 2013 and save it as a new xlsx file works also better.